# How to update a table concatenating the strings in two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, string-concatenation

I want to update a column setting it up as the concatenation of the string in one column + the file extension (in this case, '.AVI').

I tried the following but it affects 0 rows; I know for a fact that there are records which have a 'FALSE' value for Video_Name.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
declare @creativity varchar
update [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-02-26 W6] 
set Video_Name=concat(@creativity,'.AVI') where Video_Name = 'false' and
@creativity=Creativity
```

Comment: Is your server set up with case sensitive collation? In which case 'FALSE' != 'false'

Comment: @MatthewEvans nope, it's not case sensitive

Comment: @creativity has a value of `NULL`.  What are you trying to do?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want the variable creativity to be the string contained in the column Creativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
declare @creativity varchar(255);  -- length is really important

set @creativity = <some value goes here> ;  -- value is really important

update [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-02-26 W6] 
    set Video_Name = concat(@creativity, '.AVI')
    where Video_Name = 'false' and
          Creativity =  @creativity;
```

Or perhaps you just want:

```
update [UK_Telco_Pressure_2018Q3_2019-02-26 W6] 
    set Video_Name = concat(creativity, '.AVI')
    where Video_Name = 'false' ;
```